# Use do, if, and funcall to define (satisfy fun lst) which returns a list of the items in a list that satisfy a function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, funcall

I've been looking around and still don't understand how funcall works. Would really appreciate if someone can give me a suggestion on ways to approach an think about the problem. I know that "fun" will have to be a predicate function, but after that I'm stuck

btw, an item satisfies a function if the function returns true when that item is used as the function’s argument.

Comment: Do you have your code which does not work?

Comment: You can call any function with FUNCALL.

Answer (score 2):

```
(funcall #'+ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)

;        ^   -------+-------
;        |          |
;        |          Arguments
;        Function

; returns 36
```

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. Could you give me some suggestion on how to approach the problems mentioned in the title?

Answer (score 2):

`(funcall '+ 1 2 3)` returns the same result as `(+ 1 2 3) => 6`

The advantage is that in the former case, the function can be a variable.

```
(setq fun '+)
(funcall fun 1 2 3) => 6
```

A similar function is apply, where the arguments are grouped into a list:

```
(apply '+ '(1 2 3)) => 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the instruction, could you give me some suggestion on how to think about the problem?

Comment: Use loop to test each of the elements of lst by calling (funcall fun item) and if the result is true you accumulate the item in the result.

Answer (score 0):

To your problem:

```
(defun fun-satisfiers (pred-fun list)
  (let ((acc nil))
    (do ((l list (cdr l)))
        ((null l) (nreverse acc))
      (if (funcall pred-fun (car l))
          (setf acc (cons (car l) acc))))))
```

Such kind of a function exists in base common-lisp already as `filter`.